# YouTube RSS of Most Recent Videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get an RSS feed for the most recent videos uploaded to YouTube.  Not by a specific user or that contains a specific keyword - I'm looking for a feed link that will show all the most recent videos in the order they're published.

Here's what I got so far but it's definitely missing a ton:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos/-/*?v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&alt=rss
```

Does anyone know a link to YouTube's most recent uploads RSS feed?

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer get the most recent that was deprecated on the 12th September 2013. The only feed you can now get seems to be `most_popular` if you check [YouTube Feeds Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#Videos_feed) and scroll down to standard feeds you will find a note that states that it was deprecated.

Not sure what you are doing with the link you have given though as that seems to give you the most recent videos with the latest at the top sorted at date when I tried it. If you can be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to do I may be able to help further.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a real-time feed of all the most recent videos published to YouTube.  Also, I've been searching to see if YouTube has a publicly viewable sitemap anywhere.

Comment: I don't think there is any real time api you can call on they want to try and restrict load on there infrastructure and people retrieving real-time data just puts more load on the system. The link you showed above almost does what you want why can't you run that every 5 mins and do some sort of diff to find new results.